# remove words from a Map in java

Tags: java, file, dictionary

I have a txt file which contains many words. I have to extract from that file keywords. I have made this using this example http://crunchify.com/java-how-to-find-maximum-occurrence-of-words-from-text-file/ but i have as keywords also words like (the is of on and) how i can do if i want to remove this words from that Map?
I have think to create a List which contains words to remove and compare with map's element.But it is an hard work...have you some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a list, you will have to check each key from that map to the list and then decide whether to remove that key,value pair or keep it.

You can use a set rather than a list,
Create a set of all keys you want to remove and once your map is created use the function ->

```
yourMap.keySet().removeAll(setOfRemovableKeywords);
```

This will remove all the key value pairs you put in `setOfRemovableKeywords` set and will clean your map of values you do not need.